# Bash regex comparison issue

Tags: regex, bash

I have the following function

```
checkFormat()
{
        local funcUserName=$1
        if [[ "$funcUserName" != [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9] ]];then
                echo "1"
        else
                echo "0"
        fi
}

if [[ $string != [a-zA-Z0-9]* ]]
```

Only returns true if the first character is not [a-zA-Z0-9]
    if [[ $string != [a-zA-Z0-9]{5} ]]

Never returns true.

```
if [[ $string != [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9] ]]
```

Returns as I want it to. 
Why is this?

The code is to check that a username is 5 characters long and alphanumeric i.e. 
Joe12 or 12345 but not %$134.

bash version 4.2.37

Comment: Good Q except you should include sample input (both good and bad). Good luck.

Comment: What do you actually want to check with your reg ex?Give some examples

Comment: None of this is regex. It's a different kind of pattern called globs. They can look similar, but they're not the same.

Comment: I managed to emit my regex example. Oops. [[ $string =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}*$ ]] didn't work when I reversed the logic.

Comment: @joemobaggins `[[ $string =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$ ]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to replace

```
if [[ $string != [a-zA-Z0-9]{5} ]]
```

by

```
if [[ ! $string =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}*$ ]]
```

to match a regex.

Comment: Hey, thanks allot, that works. When I tried [[  $string =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}*$ ]] and reversed the logic, It didn't work. Why so?

Comment: This works for me with bash version 4: `string="a1B2c"; [[ $string =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}*$ ]] && echo match`

Comment: could you explain the && syntax to me? I realise it's an AND. But I don't understand it in this context.

Comment: Yes, `&&` is a [boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) AND. If `[[ ... ]]` is true execute `echo match`. Long version with an `else` branch: `string=a1B2c; if [[ $string =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}*$ ]]; then echo match; else echo "no match"; fi`